# How do I account for a Bootstrap 4 fixed navbar getting taller when screen get narrower

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

So I have a fixed navbar using Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark container">
        <a href="http://jthink.net/index.jsp" class="navbar-brand">
            JThink
        </a>
...
```

In my body tag I have added padding to account for the size of the fixed nav bar

```
<body style="padding-top: 100px;">
```

But of course if the screen size is not wide enough for the nav bar (such as a phone) the navbar becomes higher to fit in the links. Hence 100px is no longer large enough to avoid content being hidden by the nav bar.

So how am I meant to deal with this ?

The actual page I am working on is http://www.jthink.net/

Comment: Can't you use a mobile breakpoint to make navbar dropdown like it is so nicely designed to do? It seems you stripped the bootstrap menu abit?

Comment: Probably more info please, this all new to me.

Comment: Check these examples out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbars/

Comment: You're welcome, if you have an example i can help here to improve it. If you need me to.

Comment: Sure I dont find nav bar as intuitive as some components, this page http://www.jthink.net/ exhibits the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark container text-center">

        <a href="http://jthink.net/index.jsp" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="http://www.jthink.net/images/icon32.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            JThink
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://blog.jthink.net">
                Blog
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/jaikozforum">
                User Forum
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/songkong">
                SongKong
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://jthink.net/jaikoz">
                Jaikoz
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://albunack.net" target="_blank">
                Albunack
            </a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/index.jsp">
               Jaudiotagger
            </a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you. The indent of my code is not good, but it had to be indented line by line (i think) so messy code, but readable for you i hope.

The navbar becomes a sort of dropdown menu (with hamburger button).

The point of this all is: You use bootstrap's functions this way nicely, imho.

Good luck with it:)

Comment: HI, I have implemented a version of your solution please see http://www.jthink.net again but not showing the menu would you know why. (I haven't added the fix for IE8 but I dont need that)

Comment: Site doesnt load a.t.m. :(

Comment: its look the machine has gone down, will have to contact my service provider

Comment: hi @Rustyjim back up

Comment: hi your html is nested wrong. get "navbar-collapse" element outside of "button" element like in the example i showed, will tidy it up :)

Comment: Thanks that was the bug, okay it does work now thanks, although if you do click on the collapsed button then the nav bar expands in height and covers text, but myabe that is not an issue ?

Comment: My example is fixed-top, it you use static-top plus remove body padding-top, you get a "push content down"  menu.

Comment: but I think I want fixed top not sticky top, anyway its fine no big deal.